# Authentication form with a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I need help with this authentication form.

This is the xml file:

```
  <USER_LIST>
    <user>
      <name>giulio</name>
      <password>prova</password>
    </user>
    <user>
      <name>giulia</name>
      <password>prova1</password>
    </user>
    <user>
      <name>renato</name>
      <password>zero</password>
    </user>
  </USER_LIST>
```

and this is the code i wrote:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load("dati.txt");

            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//user"))
            {
                String User = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
                String Pass = node.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;

                if (User == textBox1.Text && Pass == textBox2.Text)
                {
                    button1.Visible = true;
                    dlt_btn.Visible = true;
                    button3.Visible = true;
                    button3.Visible = true;
                    button5.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password!");
                }
            } 
        }
```

But like this, for example, if i login with the name "renato" and password "zero"
it give me back two times the message box "Invalid Username or Password!" and the third time it show the button needed. I know why but i can't think another way to do it. This is my very first project and i started coding like yesterday, so i'm sorry if ask you a stupid thing like this.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Because the loop checks all nodes one by one and for each node which doesn't match with given user/pass, shows the message box.

Comment: Please don't do this.  Your system is insecure, you are are storing clear text passwords !

Comment: I suppose it's just for learning purpose, otherwise, it's obviously insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's just for learning purpose or an assignment which should be kept as simple, otherwise it's not secure at all.

You don't need to use a loop. Currently your loop loop checks all nodes one by one and for each node which doesn't match with given user/pass, shows the message box, that's why you see the message box until the loop reaches to the correct user/pass.

Without using a loop, you can check if the given user/pass exists in your xml file easily this way:

```
var userName = userNameTextBox.Text;
var password = passwordTextBox.Text;
var match = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(@"d:\users.xml")
    .Elements("user")
    .Where(x => x.Element("name")?.Value == userName &&
                x.Element("password")?.Value == password)
    .Any();
```

Then if the `match` is not true, you can show message box.

Comment: yeah it's just for learning! Anyway i tried your solution but the var match stay false also if the username and password are correct...

Comment: i don't know why but it doesen't work, the var match is always false...

Comment: Probably because of a mistake like using username text box instead of password text box in code or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the message box will display each time you check an entry in the XML that doesn't match.

The simplest way to do this with minimal changes to your code is like this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("dati.txt");

    bool found = false;

    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//user"))
    {
        String User = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        String Pass = node.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;

        if (User == textBox1.Text && Pass == textBox2.Text)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        dlt_btn.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button5.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password!");
    }
}
```

We create a variable called `found` and set it to `false`. This is to ensure that if the XML is empty or there are no matches that we fail the check.

Then we loop over the results and we set `found = true` if a match is found. We call break to break out of the loop.

Once the loop is complete we check to see if our local variable is true:

```
if (found)
```

This is shorthand for `if (found == true)`

If it's true then we enable your buttons as before. If it's not true then we display the error message.

It will only display the error message once.

Comment: i tried as you said (and i also tried like this before) but when i put as user and pass the third one (renato zero) it give me back two times invalid user and password and didn't show me at all the buttons. If i put the first user and pass (giulio prova) it simply doesen't show me nothing

Comment: Can you try copying my code from above and using it? Unless you are pressing the button twice there's no way it should show the error message twice.

Comment: I've just tested this with my code above and your xml file and I only see the error message once using renato/zero.

Comment: i copied and past your code but it realy doesen't work and i don't understand why. But with your suggestion of the bool flag i have find out a solution, i post it to show you

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution, that works:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username;
    string password;
    string CurrentUser = "";
    string CurrentPwd = "";
    bool LoginStatus = false;

    username = textBox1.Text;
    password = textBox2.Text;

    XmlDocument xmxdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmxdoc.Load("dati.txt");
    XmlNodeList xmlnodelist = xmxdoc.GetElementsByTagName("user");

    foreach (XmlNode xn in xmlnodelist)
    {
        XmlNodeList xmlnl = xn.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode xmln in xmlnl)
        {
            if (xmln.Name == "name")
            {
                if (xmln.InnerText == username)
                {
                    CurrentUser = username;
                }
            }
            if (xmln.Name == "password")
            {
                if (xmln.InnerText == password)
                {
                    CurrentPwd = password;
                }
            }
        }
        if ((CurrentUser != "") & (CurrentPwd != ""))
        {
            LoginStatus = true;
        }
    }
    if (LoginStatus == true)
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        dlt_btn.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button5.Visible = true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password!");
    }
}
```